# Manipulating the request body of HTTP thread based on the data extracted from the previous HTTP response

Tags: jmeter

I want to manipulate the request body of HTTP thread based on the data extracted (using 'Regular Expression Extractor') from the previous HTTP response.
Here is the scenario:-
I have extracted the statusFlag and statusId from 'HTTP request 1' as:
Ref name: status
Reg. Exp: "statusFlag":"(\w+)","statusId":"(\w+)"

So, first I want to check that the value of statusFlag is 'New' or not.
If it is New then I have to proceed and feed statusId in next HTTP request or else display statusFlag mismatch.

Need help. Got stuck badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) is what you're looking for. Add it after the Regular Expression Extractor and configure it as follows:

- Apply to: JMeter Variable -> `statusFlag` (or your reference name)
- Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
- Add `New` as a "Pattern to Test"

  [image: Response assertion]

The assertion will check whether "statusFlag" is "New" and if not - it will fail the sampler and report the expected and the actual value.

Optionally you can add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) after the Response Assertion, use `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` as a condition and place 2nd request as a child of the If Controller - it will be executed only if "statusFlag" is new.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more information on conditionally setting pass or fail criteria to requests in your JMeter test.

Answer (score 1):

That's how your Jmeter project should look like.
Regular Expression Extractor stores extracted value in ct variable that can be accessed in If Controller as "${ct}" == "yourvalue" and, if true, can be also sent as a part of Request 2 body using the same ${ct} reference.

[Jmeter project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt8q5.png)